# Zabbix HTTP agent 0 then Failed to connect

Tags: zabbix

*Greetings!*

I definitely want to use HTTP agent in Zabbix to monitor http-server of our services.

Is it possible to make variable value 0 then I cant reach host?
If it's "Failed to connect" make item equals 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possibile. The http_agent check becomes `unsupported` in case of connection errors and no data is added to the database.

You can create triggers with the [nodata function](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions) or you can switch to [web scenarios](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/web_monitoring).